# Question in the proof of $T_1$-axiom is equivalent to $x, y\in X, \exists U\ni x, V \ni y \quad \text{s.t} \quad U \nsubseteq V, V \nsubseteq U$

Tags: general-topology

As stated in the title, I have a question about the proof of the following statement:

> $T_1$-axiom(every finite point set is closed) is equivalent to the condition that for each pair of points of X, each has a neighborhood not containing the other. (Munkres, $\S17$ Exercise $15$)

I proved $\rightarrow$, but I couldn't prove $\leftarrow$, so I looked at the provided solution manual. The $\leftarrow$ part went like this.

> ...Conversely, assume that for each pair of points of $X$, each has a nbd not containing the other. Let $x$ be a point in $X$. *Then, for each $y \in X$($y \neq x$), there is a nbd $U_y$ of $y$ not containing $x$*, so $\{x\}^C=\bigcup_{y\neq x}U_y$ is open....

Now, I figured out that the proof works if the writing in italic is true. But I couldn't understand the italic part. I think this would not be immediate from the right hand side of the equivalence, because in order to use it, it must require that the set $\{x\}$ is open, so it could be an nbd of itself, which is not generally true. I also assumed the opposite(that all nbds of $y$ must contain $x$) to find contradiction, but I couldn't find it.

This might be a very easy/simple question, so please enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the assumption in the converse statement: that in every pair of points, one has a neighborhood not containing the other, i.e. you are assuming this is true and proving $T_1$.

Comment: @RyanShesler I initally thought about this, but wouldn't this require for $\{x\}$ to be an open set? so that it could be a nbd of itself?

Comment: No, it's not saying two points can be separated by disjoint open sets, that's Hausdorff or $T_2$. Its saying exactly that for each $y \neq x$, there is a nbhd $U_y$ of $y$ that does not contain $x$.

Comment: @RyanShesler Oh....so I get it now. I thought the condition was telling that the each $U$ and $V$ shouldn't contain $V$ and $U$(resp)...The question was that it shouldn't contain $y$ or $x$. Aha. So my mathematical description of the problem in the title is wrong. Right?

Comment: @JoshuaWoo If $U,V$ denote neighbourhoods, then yes.